# The multi-part identifier "t1.customer_code" could not be bound?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select t1.customer_code from pbosdeposit t1,pbosinvoice t2
inner join sap_customer t3 ON 
t3.customer_id = 
(select t4.id from customer t4 where t4.customer_code = t1.customer_code)
```

i tried many ways to do it but it still show multi-part identifier could not be bound.
Can someone explain what does multi-part identifier means?

Table Structure for sap_customer

```
CREATE TABLE sap_customer (
  customer_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  sap_cardcode VARCHAR(15),
  void_flg SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
  status_ind SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,  
  err_msg VARCHAR(250),
  last_update_by VARCHAR(32),
  last_update_on DATETIME,
  created_by VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  created_on DATETIME NOT NULL  
    )
```

Sample Data

```
056e322ae18b401392386c129fe49ae7    CT-000001   0   1   NULL    NULL    NULL    5   2017-06-30 19:03:37.427
```

Table Structure for pbosinvoice

```
CREATE TABLE pbosinvoice(
  id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  inv_type VARCHAR(3),
  inv_num VARCHAR(20),
  inv_date DATE,
  inv_due_date DATE,
  customer_code VARCHAR(10),
  customer_name VARCHAR(150),
  payment_ind VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  org_amt DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
  tax_amt DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
  inv_amt DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
  cleared_amt DECIMAL(12,2) DEFAULT 0,
  void_flg SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
  surcharge_inv_flg SMALLINT DEFAULT 0,
  last_update_by VARCHAR(32),
  last_update_on DATETIME,
  created_by VARCHAR(32),
  created_on DATETIME
)
```

Sample Data

```
0d1c7bd169b94732b771f75c61ea2713    I01 VI17010013  24/01/2017  23/02/2017  C0001   ASIALINK CARGO & PACKING AGENCY SDN BHD F   260.00  0.00    260.00  260.00  0   NULL    NULL    6   24/01/2017 11:46:42 AM
```

Table Structure for pbosdeposit

```
 CREATE TABLE pbosdeposit (
  id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  customer_code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  deposit_num VARCHAR(9),
  transaction_date DATE,
  transaction_type VARCHAR(4),
  payment_type VARCHAR(1),
  transaction_amt DECIMAL(10,4),
  cleared_amt DECIMAL(10,4),
  remarks VARCHAR(150),
  issued_date DATE,
  issued_bank VARCHAR(50),
  issued_bank_location VARCHAR(100),
  expiry_date DATE,
  ref_num VARCHAR(20),
  chq_num VARCHAR(20),
  card_num VARCHAR(20),
  card_type VARCHAR(1),
  voided_by VARCHAR(32),
  voided_on DATETIME,
  last_update_by VARCHAR(32),
  last_update_on DATETIME,
  created_by VARCHAR(32),
  created_on DATETIME
)
```

Sample Data

```
20e06bb857124f1cbd8ba60712aff4c5    C0001   D16110012   14/11/2016  CASH    C   3000.0000   3000.0000   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    6   28/11/2016 7:42:05 AM
```

Table Structure for customer

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
     id                     VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     customer_code          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     customer_name          VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
     co_reg_no              VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     tax_identification_no  VARCHAR(20),
     acc_status             VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     remarks                VARCHAR(150),
     last_update_by         VARCHAR(32),
     last_update_on         DATETIME,
     created_by             VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
     created_on             DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

Sample Data

```
829yfh823f793f7f32  C0001   ASIALINK CARGO & PACKING AGENCY SDN BHD 214124  135276311515    A   NULL    NULL    NULL    -   22/09/2016 12:25:00 PM
```

Comment: WHERE t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
is missing at the end of the query.

Comment: Still come out with the same error t1.customer_code is a multpart identifier

Comment: Share the table structure, sample data and exact error message please

Comment: the title is the exact error message. i've already provide the table structure and sample data

Comment: Never use the comma syntax with the FROM clause. It's just nasty to deal with. use joins instead

Comment: 1. Your query is a mess. You are using a mixture of implicit and explicit joins, as well as a derived table. 2. Your sample data s useless. You've provided the table structure as DDL, Please provide sample data as DML. 3. We don't need to know about all the columns in your tables, just those that are relevant to the question. Read about creating a [mcve] and please fix your question accordingly. 4. I'm guessing the connecion between `pbosdeposit` and `pbosinvoice` is the customer code. Don't make me (Or SQL Server) guess...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your requirements, your sample data should yield no results.
That's because the only row provided in `customer` table has an `id` value that does not match the `customer_id` in the only row you provided in table 
`sap_customer`.

However, Your query is a mess and should be constructed correctly (and hopefully will yield results on the actual data you have).

So first, create and populate sample tables: (Remember, only the columns actually used in the query, other columns only creates noise)

```
CREATE TABLE sap_customer (
    customer_id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    -- We don't cate about all the other column for this question...
)
INSERT INTO sap_customer (customer_id) VALUES ('056e322ae18b401392386c129fe49ae7')

CREATE TABLE pbosinvoice (
    id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_code VARCHAR(10)
    -- We don't cate about all the other column for this question...
)
INSERT INTO pbosinvoice (id, customer_code) VALUES ('0d1c7bd169b94732b771f75c61ea2713', 'C0001')

CREATE TABLE pbosdeposit (
    id VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    -- We don't cate about all the other column for this question...
)
INSERT INTO pbosdeposit (id, customer_code) VALUES ('20e06bb857124f1cbd8ba60712aff4c5', 'C0001')

CREATE TABLE customer
(
    id                     VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_code          VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    -- We don't cate about all the other column for this question...
)
INSERT INTO customer (id, customer_code) VALUES ('829yfh823f793f7f32', 'C0001')
```

And now, the query:

```
select t1.customer_code 
from pbosdeposit as t1
inner join pbosinvoice as t2 on t1.customer_code = t2.customer_code
inner join customer as t3 on t1.customer_code = t3.customer_code
inner join sap_customer as t4 ON t3.id = t4.customer_id
```

Please note that I've changed the order of joins between `customer` and `sap_customer`.

If the `id` value in the `customer` table was the same as the `customer_id` in the `sap_customer` table (`056e322ae18b401392386c129fe49ae7`), this query would return a single record with the value `C0001`.

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/TONQT46849)